# Rendering two components (with a Handlebars helper?)

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a `{{#resizable-column}}` block component whose width is controlled by a `{{drag-handle}}` component. In terms of markup, they are siblings, and rely on the width of their parent (displayed with flexbox).

I’d like to reduce this down to a single component that includes the column and the drag handle, ideally without any redundant markup, or any extra styles:

```
{{#resizable-column width=navWidth}}
  My content
{{/resizable-column}}
```

resulting in:

```
<div class="resizable-column" style="width: `navWidth`">
  My content
</div>
<div class="drag-handle" style="right: `navWidth`"></div>
```

This is what I had in mind:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/resizable-column">
  {{#the-column width=width}}
    {{yield}}
  {{/the-column}}

  {{drag-handle positionRight=width}}
</script>
```

but given that components and views wrap their content, this results in an additional div. Could/should this be done with a Handlebars helper?

**Edit:** I’ve got pretty close with the following:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('resizable-column', function (options) {
  Ember.Handlebars.resolveHelper(options.data.view.container, 
                                 'the-column').call(this, options);
  Ember.Handlebars.resolveHelper(options.data.view.container, 
                                 'drag-handle').call(this, options);
});
```

But the calling a helper twice doesn’t seem to work given the same options: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yepoya/3/edit

Answer (score 2):

> but given that components and views wrap their content, this results in an additional div

One potential solution is to eliminate that wrapper div. You can do it by setting `tagName` equal to an empty string. Like this:

```
App.ResizableColumnComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: ''
});
```

I do this from time to time, just be aware that the `$` method of the component won't work anymore. So calling `this.$('...')` will always return an empty jQuery selector. There are simple ways around that though.

Comment: oh cool, I didn't know you could avoid the creation of that wrapping element!

Comment: Mind blown. I don’t know why I didn’t think of that! Is it safe to do it? (I’m not going to be stung in a future version am ?!) Thanks!

Comment: From what I can tell, it's not documented anywhere, so I'm not sure if it's public or private API. That being said, Ember does use this method internally, so _if_ they were to remove it they would provide a replacement.

Comment: I guess I was concerned with a blank tagName, and whether or not that was defined behaviour

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. I don't know if you're supposed to use a blank tag name or not, but it definitely works and it's used internally. I don't think you'll run into any issues in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to pass through all options from the App.ResizableColumnComponent to the child components? I’m currently working on an approach without a wrapping component: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yepoya/3 I’m pretty close, but the options only appear to work for a single render. Any ideas? Thanks again.